# What is the probability that the sum of the squares of $3$ positive real numbers whose sum is less than $10$ is less than $16$?

Tags: probability, volume

> What is the probability that the sum of the squares of $3$ positive real numbers whose sum is less than $10$ is less than $16$?

This is how I understood the question:

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$ with

$$a+b+c<10$$

Then find the probability such that

$$a^2+b^2+c^2<16$$

There are infinitely many positive real numbers.  Know how to calculate probability?

I would like to draw a circle or triangle area. But I can't establish a connection with the triangle area or the circle.

The situations are also infinite.  This question sounds as if it will be solved from the area of a figure.  Do you think I am on the right track?

Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: No.  Your sample space or universe is finite and quite small:  $a,b,c$ such that $a+b+c<10$.  OF THOSE, what is the probability $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < 16$?  See?

Comment: By what probability distribution are you selecting your three positive reals whose sum is less than $10$?

Comment: @JMoravitz This is a problem statement $a+b+c=10$, then find the probability $a^2+b^2+c^2<16$..This is my interpretation..

Comment: "*I would like to draw a circle or triangle area*"... if my interpretation of the problem is correct, you would do better to draw a pyramid (*with vertices (0,0,0), (0,0,10),(0,10,0),(10,0,0) and a sphere of radius $4$ centered at the origin*) and compare *volumes*, not areas.

Comment: "*This is a problem statement $a+b+c=10$, then find the probability...*"  That does nothing to answer my question or clarify anything.  You need to understand that multiple probability distributions can be possible and changing from one distribution to another can lead to wildly different answers.  [See Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability))

Comment: @JMoravith I am a student, Probability is my new subject...Is this question wrong?

Comment: You are in the right track. But because you are dealing with three vairables, you need to "graph" in three dimensions, and compute volumes, instead of areas

Comment: "*Is this question wrong*"  Your presentation of it is at least.  Yes, there may be a *standard* interpretation where we assume that $(a,b,c)$ **is uniformly selected** from the *real* region $\{(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3~:~0<a,~0<b,~0<c,~a+b+c<10\}$... but that still needs to be explicitly stated for the question to be unambiguous.  Since you labeled this *combinatorics* which deals primarily with discrete scenarios, one could argue that you instead meant to pull uniformly from $\{(a,b,c)\in\color{red}{\Bbb Z^3}~:~0<a,~0<b,~0<c,~a+b+c<10\}$ instead... of course non-uniform distributions exist too

Comment: @leonbloy Thank you very much. I am trying to solve.

Comment: For positive reals $a,b, c$, when $a + b + c = 10$, we must have $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq \frac{100}{3}$ by AM-RM so geometrically speaking, the part of the sphere $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 16$ in the first octant is completely inside the tetrahedron formed by $a + b + c = 10$ and $a = 0, b = 0, c = 0$. So the probability should simply be the ratio of their volumes.

Comment: @JMoravitz I deleted combinatoric tag

Comment: @MathLover How did you get $a^2+b^2+c^2≥100/3$?

Comment: By Root Mean Square and Arithmetic Mean inequality, $ \sqrt {\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{3}} \geq \frac{a + b + c}{3}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities

Comment: @MathLover Thank you, is this a well known inequality like a AM GM? I understood..

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, the question is asking: Given a (uniformly-distributed?) random point in the tetrahedron bounded by the plane $z = 10 - x - y$ and the planes formed by the three axes, what is the probability that it lies within (1/8 of) a sphere of radius 4 centered at the origin.  Divide the volume of the sphere segment ($\frac{32\pi}{3}$) by the volume of the tetrahedron ($\frac{500}{3}$).

Or, if geometry is not your forte, try a Monte Carlo simulation:

```
import random

def random_point():
    while True:
        # Generate random point in cube 0 <= x, y, z < 10
        x = random.uniform(0, 10)
        y = random.uniform(0, 10)
        z = random.uniform(0, 10)
        # Is it within the given tetrahedral region?
        if x + y + z < 10:
            return (x, y, z)

def estimate_probability(iteration_count):
    points_in_sphere = 0
    for i in range(iteration_count):
        x, y, z = random_point()
        if x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2 < 16:
            points_in_sphere += 1
    return points_in_sphere / iteration_count
```

The `estimate_probability` function returns an average result around 0.201.  For more accuracy, use more iterations.

Answer (score -1):

Making use of geometric probability and Mathematica, one obtains

```
RegionMeasure[ ImplicitRegion[ x + y + z <= 10 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 16 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && 
z >= 0, {x, y, z}]]/RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[ x + y + z <= 10 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0, 
{x, y, z}]]
```

$$\frac{8 \pi }{125} $$

Comment: Can  the downvoter motivate it? TIA.

Comment: "*Can the downvoter motivate it?*"  -"*Making use of...mathematica*"  This should be able to be done purely by hand.  The only calculations needed come from middle-school level geometry, finding the volume of a pyramid and a sphere (*octant*) and verifying the sphere lies within the pyramid.

Comment: @JMoravetz: Can you solve it with $37$ instead of $16$ by hand? TIA.

Comment: @JMoravetz: Mathematica answers $0.696274$ in that case.